# Fix background to labels

Tags: html, css, responsive

I'm trying to fix a background image to some labels but I'm having troubles. 
I made everything responsive but I can't really figure out how to match the labels with the underlying shelves...
I'd also like to put the table div on the same level (but outside the shelves images)...
Everything will be filled with dynamic values so don't worry if you read generic labels. 

This is the code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<!-- Il viewport rende tutto ciò che c'è al suo interno responsive riadattando gli elementi fino a 240px di larghezza del display-->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
<style>


.menusx {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:7px;
}
.menu {
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left: 5px;
  margin-bottom:7px;
}
.menuitem {
  background-color:#e5e5e5;
  padding:8px;
  margin-top:7px;
}

.menudiv {
  background-image: url("http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wallpapers_1920x1200/digital-art/1/1/wooden-shelves-digital-art-hd-wallpaper-1920x1200-7977.jpg"); 
  width: 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: contain;
}

.right {
  background-color:#e5e5e5;
  float:left;
  width:20%;
  padding:14px;
  margin-top:7px;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left: 5px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width:620px) {
  /* For mobile phones: */
  .menu, .main, .right {
    width:100%;
  }
}
</style>
</head>
<body style="font-family:Verdana;color:#aaaaaa;">


<div style="overflow:auto">
 <div class="menudiv" style="overflow:auto">
  <div class="menusx">
    <div class="menuitem">Link 1 sx</div>
    <div class="menuitem">Link 2 sx</div>
    <div class="menuitem">Link 3 sx</div>
    <div class="menuitem">Link 4 sx</div>
  </div>


  <div class="menu">
    <div class="menuitem">Link 1</div>
    <div class="menuitem">Link 2</div>
    <div class="menuitem">Link 3</div>
    <div class="menuitem">Link 4</div>
  </div>
   </div>


  <div class="right">
    <h3>Table</h3>
    <p>Dynamic content of the table</p>
  </div>
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

This is the basic idea: [image: Goal]

Comment: Please share an image of your desired output.

Answer (score 1):

You may use this changes. You need to modify the "menudiv" to less width and float, so the table can be rendered on the right side, not under the link table.

The "menudiv" background-size need to have "cover" property, so the image will fill the current div size.

Then you need to modify the "menusx" and "menu" classes width to 49%, so these 2 divs will fill the full "menudiv" and the right table has 2% margin for separation from the left one.  "menusx" and "menu" width values are 49, 49 and add the menudiv margin-left 2% to it so 49+49+2 = 100% fill of the upper div.

```
.menudiv {
  background-image: url("http://static.hdw.eweb4.com/media/wallpapers_1920x1200/digital-art/1/1/wooden-shelves-digital-art-hd-wallpaper-1920x1200-7977.jpg"); 
  width: 40%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  float: left;
}
.menusx {
  float:left;
  width:49%;
  text-align:center;
  margin-bottom:7px;
}
.menu {
  float:left;
  width:49%;
  text-align:center;
  margin-left: 2%;
  margin-bottom:7px;
}
```

I hope this is what you are looking for.

Comment: although this is a step ahead it doesn't solve my problem: the background still isn't "fixed" to the labels and the table div isn't on the same line. If you check my question there's an img that should explain my objective :)

Comment: Sorry, I edited my CSS, there is a new "float: left;" at ".menudiv" class. With this, the Table div will move from the bottom, to right. Do you need to change this Table height to the link table height?

Answer (score 1):

Just move your,

```
<div class="right">
    <h3>Table</h3>
    <p>Dynamic content of the table</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

inside the `<div style="overflow:auto">` block, the code should look like,

```
<div style="overflow:auto">
  <div class="menudiv" style="overflow:auto">
    <div class="menusx">
      <div class="menuitem">Link 1 sx</div>
      <div class="menuitem">Link 2 sx</div>
      <div class="menuitem">Link 3 sx</div>
      <div class="menuitem">Link 4 sx</div>
    </div>

   <div class="menu">
    <div class="menuitem">Link 1</div>
    <div class="menuitem">Link 2</div>
    <div class="menuitem">Link 3</div>
    <div class="menuitem">Link 4</div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <h3>Table</h3>
    <p>Dynamic content of the table</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Working Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/wrtjx0x0/4/**

Hope this helps!

Comment: yeah this helps but it doesn't solve the main problem. Thanks BTW! :D